# Weird exception while trying to send an HTTP request

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

Im getting this exception while trying to get a website content by doing an HTTP request.
I tryed with several different urls (including PasteBin) and im getting a weird exception which i never got before:

```
    private static string GetWebsiteContent()
    {
        
        try
        {
            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0");

            Console.WriteLine(webClient.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/MyUrl"));
           

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Thats the method that i call, i dont it need any kind of explanation, just a simple request to a site.

The exception:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Impossibile inizializzare il sistema di configurazione ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Errore durante il cari
camento di un file di configurazione: L'inizializzatore di tipo di 'System.MarvinHash' ha generato un'eccezione. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config)
 ---> System.TypeInitializationException: L'inizializzatore di tipo di 'System.MarvinHash' ha generato un'eccezione. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Riferimento a un oggetto non im
postato su un'istanza di oggetto.
   in System.Collections.HashHelpers.GetEntropy()
   in System.OrdinalComparer.System.IWellKnownStringEqualityComparer.GetRandomizedEqualityComparer()
   in System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   in System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.get_DefaultNameHT()
   in System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(String name, Object[] args)
   in System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator.Create()
   in System.MarvinHash.GenerateSeed()
   in System.MarvinHash..cctor()
   --- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
   in System.Xml.NameTable..ctor()
   in System.Configuration.XmlUtil..ctor(Stream stream, String name, Boolean readToFirstElement, ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   in System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()
   --- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
   in System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
   in System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
   in System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   --- Fine della traccia dello stack dell'eccezione interna ---
   in System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
   in System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.PrepareClientConfigSystem(String sectionName)
   in System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String sectionName)
   in System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   in System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   in System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()
   in System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
   in System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_Sources()
   in System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.Initialize()
   in System.Net.Logging.InitializeLogging()
   in System.Net.Logging.get_On()
   in System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   in SchoolProject.WebUtils.GetWebsiteContent() in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Projects\CS\SchoolProject\WebUtils.cs:riga 25

Process finished with exit code -1,073,741,510.
```

Im tryed the following code on different computers, but the result still the same.

Im using .NET 4.0 (must)

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: I found this: https://code-examples.net/en/q/121c0b8, maybe it is helpful?

Comment: Unfortunatly not :(

Comment: I upvoted to attrackt fellow users. I read something about that problem being introduced by some windows updates ... but they should be fixed by later updates as of today. Are all machines updated regularly?

Comment: Thanks for the upvote. Yes, or atleast i think so, im using Windows 11 (Latest update) so i dont think its related to the machine itself, its also stranger bacause it wasnt happening before..

Comment: Does this happen with a completely different Solution, too? Like a plain new Console-App?

Comment: Just tried and nop, apparently in a plain-new solution seems to be working. I tried to clear/delete all the caches are reload the project completly but still giving that error in that project. Even the built version (.exe) is giving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer recommended to use `WebClient`. And it is better to use `HttpClient` instead

```
private static async Task<string> GetWebsiteContent()
{
    try
    {
         var client = new HttpClient();
         //If You Need Add Header 
         //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0");       
         var response = await client.GetAsync("https://pastebin.com/url");
         var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         return content;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
     }

        return null;
  }
```

Comment: Important side note is that HttpClient should be used as a singleton, preferably with the HttpClientFactory, otherwise marked as static - in order to avoid Socket exceptions.

Comment: This question uses ‍‍‍`.Net4.0` and it is important not to manually dispose  `HttpClient`. In fact, as I wrote, it does not cause a problem, although it is not a best practice

Comment: Well.. thanks for your answer but it doesnt fix my problem..

Comment: Why didn't solve the problem? Are you getting an error?